# Merge a specific value from one array of dicts into another if a value matches

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

How do I merge a specific value from one array of dicts into another array of dicts if a single specific value matches between them?

I have an array of dicts that represent books

`books = [{'writer_id': '123-456-789', 'index': None, 'title': 'Yellow Snow'}, {'writer_id': '888-888-777', 'index': None, 'title': 'Python for Dummies'}, {'writer_id': '999-121-223', 'index': 'Foo', 'title': 'Something Else'}]`

and I have an array of dicts that represents authors

`authors = [{'roles': ['author'], 'profile_picture': None, 'author_id': '123-456-789', 'name': 'Pat'}, {'roles': ['author'], 'profile_picture': None, 'author_id': '999-121-223', 'name': 'May'}]`

I want to take the name from `authors` and add it to the dict in `books` where the books `writer_id` matches the authors `author_id`.

My end result would ideally change the book array of dicts to be (notice the first dict now has the value of 'name': 'Pat' and the second book has 'name': 'May'):

`books = [{'writer_id': '123-456-789', 'index': None, 'title': 'Yellow Snow', 'name': 'Pat'}, {'writer_id': '888-888-777', 'index': None, 'title': 'Python for Dummies'}, {'writer_id': '999-121-223', 'index': 'Foo', 'title': 'Something Else', 'name': 'May'}]`

My current solution is:

```
for book in books:
  for author in authors:
    if book['writer_id'] == author['author_id']:
      book['author_name'] = author['name']
```

And this works. However, the nested statements bother me and feel unwieldy. I also have a number of other such structures so I end up with a function that has a bunch of code resembling this in it:

```
for book in books:
      for author in authors:
        if book['writer_id'] == author['author_id']:
          book['author_name'] = author['name']

books_with_foo = []
for book in books:
      for thing in things:
        if something:
          // do something


for blah in books_with_foo:
      for book_foo in otherthing:
        if blah['bar'] == stuff['baz']:
          // etc, etc.
```

Alternatively, how would you aggregate data from multiple database tables into one thing... some of the data comes back as dicts, some as arrays of dicts?

Comment: I'm going to ask the X-Y question: why are you keeping all of this in dicts, when it appears that you have a lot of need to cross-reference the info?  I would think that a data base (e.g. pandas frames) would serve you better -- you could index data entries by any value, rather than having to import things according to a clunky value search.

Comment: Good question and I do not have a good answer. I am trying to solve a problem that I encountered after retrieving data from a database that I have no control over in a code base that I am only just starting to look at (and that I have no previous involvement with). If there is a better way to do what I am trying to do (merge various values from various DB tables into one new data structure) then I am all ears.

Comment: @Stuart yes, `pandas` is your friend; you can convert a series of dicts to a cohesive `dataframe` easily

Comment: This is not the place to give you a tutorial on data frames.  Once you're familiar with the concept, I suggest that you convert these dicts to data frames.  The present keys become your column headings.  Simple filters will allow you to access corresponding data as needed, or to import that data into a new column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas is almost definitely going to help you here.  Convert your dicts to `DataFrames` for easier manipulation, then merge them:

```
import pandas as pd

authors = [{'roles': ['author'], 'profile_picture': None, 'author_id': '123-456-789', 'name': 'Pat'}, {'roles': ['author'], 'profile_picture': None, 'author_id': '999-121-223', 'name': 'May'}]
books = [{'writer_id': '123-456-789', 'index': None, 'title': 'Yellow Snow'}, {'writer_id': '888-888-777', 'index': None, 'title': 'Python for Dummies'}, {'writer_id': '999-121-223', 'index': 'Foo', 'title': 'Something Else'}]

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(books)
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(authors)

df1['author_id'] = df1.writer_id
df1 = df1.set_index('author_id')
df2 = df2.set_index('author_id')

result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

you may find [this page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) helpful for different ways of combining (merging, concatenating, etc) separate `DataFrames`.

Comment: I appreciate this answer and will mark it as accepted after a slightly longer period. Sadly, I am not permitted to add the pandas library to this project so I will have to find another way.

Comment: Oh well... whoever made that decision may want to reconsider.  Pandas is an extremely helpful too for exactly what you're trying to do.